# ANTLR3 python runtime not detected

Tags: python, optimization, runtime, antlr3, particle-swarm

I want to use fstpso package in python which needs ANTLR3 python runtime.
I downloaded **antlr_python_runtime-3.1.3.tar.gz** from http://www.antlr3.org/download/Python/ and ran the command `sudo python setup.py install`. The output of the command was
 `Installed /path/to/python/packages/antlr_python_runtime-3.1.3-py2.7.egg`

But after this when I try to import fstpso module in python, it throws the error
`The ANTLR3 python runtime was not detected; pyfuzzy cannot import FST-PSO's FLC files`

I am using python 2.7.12 on linux.

Is there something I did wrong? Or I have to update any PATH in the environment?
Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I am also getting the same error, did you get any solution?

Comment: @BhaskarDhariyal, I havent got any solution, yet.

Comment: I raised an issue on git repo; he replied the owner replied there; you could check https://github.com/aresio/fst-pso/issues/2

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will keep following the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fst-pso main developer. In the last days I reimplemented the Sugeno reasoner from scratch, to finally remove the pufuzzy/ANTL3 dependency. I just uploaded the new package on PyPI.

Now you can pip install the new version of fst-pso (v 1.4.0); please let me know if that works correctly.